# How do I get results of SQL data change statement with triggers updates applied?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have a requirement where I need to get the immediate result of an update statement. I saw that I can do that by using the SQL [data-change-statement modifiers](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ias?topic=statement-result-sets-from-sql-data-changes). However, I'm not being able to get the final result after applying all associated triggers. For example, let's say I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT empno, salary FROM FINAL TABLE
    (UPDATE employee SET salary = salary * 1.10 WHERE job = 'CLERK')
```

And let's suppose I have a trigger that does the following:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER EXTRA_PAY_RISE AFTER UPDATE ON employee 
REFERENCING OLD AS oldrow  
NEW AS newrow 
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL 
WHEN (newrow.dept = 'sales')
UPDATE employee SET salary = salary * 1.01 WHERE name = newrow.name;
```

How can I get the result from the first select statement containing the updates applied by all of the associated triggers (if that's possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger and either `NEW TABLE` (in any case) or `FINAL TABLE` (if you don't have `AFTER UPDATE` triggers).

If you can't use `BEFORE` trigger to implement your update logic, then you can't use a data-change-statement to achieve your goal.

Comment: Yes, I think this solution can be useful to other people who will face similar issues in the future. But in my case I need to use the `AFTER UPDATE`. I'll probably sort it out by tweaking the source code.